# ThenInclude missing in Entity Framework Core 3.1.4?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I want to use [`.ThenInclude` as per the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.theninclude?view=efcore-3.1)

in this code snippet:

```
Frame = context.Frames
               .Include("Product")
               .Include("Parts").ThenInclude("FrameComponent")
               .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Product.Item_Number == bo.ProductCode),
```

However I get an error

> 'IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'ThenInclude' and no accessible extension method 'ThenInclude' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Include()` in EF Core works with lambda expressions (as per the docs you've referenced) - not with strings.

Try something like

```
Frame = context.Frames
               .Include(f => f.Product)
               .Include(f => f.Parts).ThenInclude(p => p.FrameComponent)
               .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Product.Item_Number == bo.ProductCode)
```

Comment: Also with strings. But then there's no `ThenInclude`.

Answer (score 2):

Just see the [differences in return types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.include?view=efcore-3.1):

With string argument:

```cs
public static IQueryable<TEntity> Include<TEntity>
    (this IQueryable<TEntity> source, string navigationPropertyPath)
        where TEntity : class;
```

With lambda expression argument:

```cs
public static IIncludableQueryable<TEntity,TProperty> Include<TEntity,TProperty>
    (this IQueryable<TEntity> source, Expression<Func<TEntity,TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath)
        where TEntity : class;
```

The latter overload returns an `IIncludableQueryable`, an empty interface to which `EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions` adds `ThenInclude` extension methods.

The reason, of course, is that for `ThenInclude` the type of the preceding navigation property must be known at compile-time.

The same effect can also be achieved with the string overload. It accepts dot-separated nested properties, like `Include("Product.FrameComponent")`.